# Can't load a custom UITableViewCell inside a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need help with loading a custom `UITableViewCell` inside a `UITableViewController`. The intended result is to have a single UITableViewController with 3 `UITableViewCell` in it: 2 of the 3 are regular UITableViewCell, one is a custom UITableView subclass, named **SubscriptionContentCell**. The 3 cells are displayed based on the conditions of contents are present, not present or still loading from the server. I'm not having problem with the conditions, but with the stock

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method in which I placed a code to pick the appropriate UITableViewCell. This is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    id cell;

    if ([deactivableOrNotContents count] > 0) {
        cellIdentifier = @"subscriptionCell";
    } else {
        if (getPurchasedHasFired == true) {
            cellIdentifier = @"noContentsAvailable";
        } else {
            cellIdentifier = @"loadingCell";
        }
    }

    if ([deactivableOrNotContents count] > 0) {
        SubscriptionContentCell *contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell = contentCell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *standardCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell = standardCell;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([deactivableOrNotContents count] > 0) {
            cell = [[SubscriptionContentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        } else {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The problem I'm having is a `SIGABRT` on line:

```
SubscriptionContentCell *contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

even if I imported the class.

This is the UITableView cell inside the UITableViewController in my storyboard file:

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: why are you doing two if checks? you can do them in one

Comment: probabaly the cell identifier is getting nil because you are allocating them at different place

Comment: Check the XIB to see if there are any `IBOutlet`s set that no longer exist in your code.

Comment: do you set the cell identifiers on your storyboard?

Comment: @rebello95 The 3rd comment did the job right, now it works :O. I can't believe that a single IBOutlet can cause such a strange crash without any console messages :-/. I can give you the best answer?

Comment: @Aluminum Great - sure, I just posted a more detailed answer.

Comment: Also the last if is redundant. It won't be executed ever. Check the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SIGABRT` messages can be caused by several things. The most common one is probably having an `IBOutlet` that is still linked in the *interface file* but has been **removed** in your *code*.

Since you're loading your `UITableViewCell` objects from `XIB` files, this is most likely the cause of your issue. Check your `SubscriptionContentCell` interface file and see if there are any `IBOutlet`s linked to subviews that have since been removed from your class's code.